# Food safe Green flame

Tags: everyday-chemistry, combustion, color

I'm a master bartender that is trying to create a green flame that is food safe and can be burned indoors safely. I'd be interested in any other colors as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A pinch of food grade borax should work.

Comment: @Mithoron, your comment was tongue-in-cheek, I assume (no pun intended!). Borax is *not* considered safe to ingest (https://www.foodauthority.nsw.gov.au/consumer/keeping-food-safe/other-topics/borax-and-boric-acid: "The Food Standards Code does not permit borax to be used in foods.") In the USA, the Pure Food and Drug Act was written *because* of borates in food (among other kissues): https://guides.loc.gov/chronicling-america-pure-food-drug-act-1906 Ummm... would you suggest copper chloride, for a nice green flame???

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You assume wrong. If borax wasn't used in food, there would be no need for mentioning it in such documents. On the other hand copper chloride isn't mentioned, because nobody uses it - it's much more dangerous. Borax got LD50 about as high as table salt, and is used similarly in a few Asian countries.

Comment: Borax is a _sodium_ borate. Will the D lines interfere with the desired green coloration? Can we use boric acid?

Comment: There is none. Your only options are yellow, red and some in-betweens, all other flames are unsafe indoor and require strong ventilation.

Comment: @Mithoron, yet borax is banned in food in USA, Australia, and likely other countries... perhaps it has to do with life expectancy -- if they don't expect one to *live long enough* to accumulate a significant amount of boron, it doesn't matter. As for copper chloride, that definitely *was* meant tongue in cheek! Take that statement with a grain of salt... but not CuCl2

Comment: @OscarLanzi Not too much, but it changes the shade. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored_fire

Comment: Trimethylborate burns green is volatile but it reacts with water . Fill a butane lighter with a mix and use it to light the alcohol. It's been a while since the Coconut Grove https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoanut_Grove_fire so we probably need some more fire in bars.

Comment: I'm trying to make different colored flames on cocktails. It has to be food safe and safe to burn inside.